# Trying to get files from today date and result is displaying yesterday date files as well (Unix Korn Shell)

Tags: shell, date, unix, find, ls

I'm trying to get today files with a pattern but i'm getting files from yesterday as well, I'm trying to do this:

```
find /mydir/files/*GEN* -mtime -1 -exec ls -l {} \;
-rw-r--r--   1 testuser      testuser      20 Mar  7 17:05 /mydir/files/900.GEN
-rw-r--r--   1 testuser      testuser      20 Mar  7 17:14 /mydir/files/901.GEN
-rw-r--r--   1 testuser      testuser      20 Mar  8 16:35 /mydir/files/902.GEN
```

do you know why is displaying files from yesterday date?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

I had to do a little tricky right there.

```
find /mydir/files/*GEN* -mtime -1 -exec ls -l {} \; | grep "$(date +"%b %e")"
```

also I'm adding an "Extra filter" to search by today date.